# Save react-grid-layout in database and restore it

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-grid-layout

I'm using react-grid-layout to create scheduller :

[enter link description here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout)

[image]

I would like to know if this is possible to save the layout into a mysql database and restore it ?

**My idea is to store the information in local storage and to transfer the local storage content to MySQL...**

https://strml.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/7-localstorage.html

I hope that's possible, because we spend a lot of time to get this result.

Answer (score 2):

Get the current layout using the `onLayoutChange` event and save its output into a database as a `VARCHAR`.

Yes, it is possible.

[Source](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/883)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You gave me a link I red 10 times... Please is someone has an exemple code ?  Thank you again.